# rotating text,marquee is not appropriate

Tags: android, android-studio, marquee

I have added this code to my MainActivity.java:

```
tv6.setText("11111111111\n"+strPokus2+"\nA\n"+strPokus+"\nB");
        tv6.setSingleLine(true);
        tv6.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        tv6.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        tv6.setSelected(true);
```

HOWEVER, the text is still static, not rotating/moving. What's wrong ??

HERE IS MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml below it:

```
package com.example.tablelayout6;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.icu.text.MeasureFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TabWidget;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

import android.text.TextUtils;

import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public boolean g=true;
public Integer N=1;
public String a="2";
private EditText editText1;
private EditText linear;
private Integer[] hodnoty =new Integer[10];
private String[] koal=new String[10];
private float[] shap=new float[10];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public boolean iswinning(Integer J,int ii) {
return true;

    }

    public Integer fact (Integer f) {
        if (f==0) return 1;
else return f*fact((Integer) (f-1));
    }

    //T pocetHracu


    public Integer[] stringToArray(String binary) {
        Integer[] arrayOfPLayers=new Integer[binary.length()];
         for(int i=0;i<binary.length();i++) {
             arrayOfPLayers[i]=Integer.parseInt("" + binary.charAt(i));

         }
         return arrayOfPLayers;
    }

    //N je pocet koalici
    public void click5(View view) {

        int pocetHracu=Integer.toBinaryString(N-1).length();
        Integer[][] koalice=new Integer[N][pocetHracu];
        Integer[][] koalice2=new Integer[N][pocetHracu];
        Integer[][] koalice3=new Integer[N][pocetHracu];

        TextView tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        for (Integer ith=0;ith<N;ith++) {
            for(Integer T=0;T<pocetHracu;T++) {
              String StringPadded=stf(Integer.toBinaryString(ith),pocetHracu-Integer.toBinaryString(ith).length());
              koalice[ith][T]=stringToArray(StringPadded)[T];
              koalice2[ith][T]=stringToArray(StringPadded)[T];
              koalice3[ith][T]=stringToArray(StringPadded)[T];
            }
        }
        float[] shap=new float[pocetHracu];
        float[] vyhryKoalici = new float[N];
        Integer[] isSwing=new Integer[pocetHracu];

        for (int i=0; i<N;i++) {
            editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(330+i);
            String a=editText1.getText().toString();
            float f1 = Float.parseFloat(a);
         vyhryKoalici[i]=f1;
        }

        Integer[] kolikJeSwingu=  new Integer[pocetHracu];




String S="";

        String kde="j";

        Integer jth;
        for (int p = 0; p < pocetHracu; p++) {
            isSwing[p] =0;
            kolikJeSwingu[p]=N;
        }

//        Integer swingove2=pocetHracu*N;
Integer bool=1;
        Integer canBanzhaf=1;

for(Integer contr=0;contr<N;contr++)
{
    if(vyhryKoalici[contr]!=0 && vyhryKoalici[contr]!=1) {
        canBanzhaf=0;
    }
}
        for(Integer T=0;T<pocetHracu;T++) {
          for (Integer ith = 0; ith < N; ith++) {

              bool = 1;

//vyhryKoalici[ith];
//musis najit jth<N pro ktere koalice3[jth]=S-ith
              if ((koalice[ith][T] == 1) && (vyhryKoalici[ith]==1)) {
                  koalice3[ith][T] = 0;
                  for (jth = 0; jth < N; jth++) {
                      for (Integer k = 0; k < pocetHracu; k++)
                      {
                          //if (k != T && koalice[ith][k] != koalice3[jth][k]) {
                          if ((k != T) && (koalice[ith][k] != koalice3[jth][k])) {
                              bool = 0;
                           //   swingove2--;
                              kde+="\nk"+k.toString()+"T"+T.toString()+">";
                          }
                      }
                      kde+="\njth"+jth.toString()+"ith"+ith.toString()+"T"+T.toString();
//(vyhryKoalici[jth]
                     if ((vyhryKoalici[jth]==0) && (bool == 1)) {
                          isSwing[T]++;
                      }
                     bool=1;
                  }
                  koalice3[ith][T]=1;
                  bool=1;
              }

          }
        }



//kolikJeSwingu(Integer TmaSwing, Integer pocetHracu, Integer pocetKoalici,
//                                   Integer[][] koal, Integer[] koalicePriKtereJeSwing, float[] vyhryKoal)

            for (Integer ith = 0; ith < N; ith++) {
                for(Integer T=0;T<pocetHracu;T++) {
//isSwingBool(Integer kteraKoalice, Integer TmaSwing, Integer pocetHracu, Integer pocetKoalici,
//                               Integer[][] koal, Integer[] koalicePriKtereJeSwing, float[] vyhryKoal) {

                 //   kolikJeSwingu[T]+=kolikJeSwingu(T, pocetHracu, N,
                  //          koalice, koalice[ith],vyhryKoalici);


                    if (koalice[ith][T] == 1) {
                        koalice2[ith][T] = 0;
                        for (jth = 0; jth < N; jth++) {
                            bool = 1;
                            for (int k = 0; k < pocetHracu; k++) {
                                if (k != T && koalice[ith][k] != koalice2[jth][k]) {
                                    bool = 0;
                                }
                            }

                            int bool2=0;
                            koalice2[ith][T] = 1;

                            if (vyhryKoalici[ith] == 1 && vyhryKoalici[jth] == 0) {
                                for (int k = 0; k < pocetHracu; k++) {
                                    if (koalice[ith][k] != koalice2[jth][k]) {
                                        bool2++;
                                    }
                                }

                            //    if(bool2==1) {
                             //       isSwing[T]++;
                             //   }

                            }
                            koalice2[ith][T] = 1;
                            Integer t = 0;
                            for (int p = 0; p < pocetHracu; p++) {
                                t += koalice[ith][p];
                            }
                            // Integer[] isSwing=new Integer[pocetHracu];

                            if (bool == 1) {
                                shap[T] += (float) ((float) fact(t - 1) * fact(pocetHracu - t) / (float) (fact(pocetHracu)) * (float) (vyhryKoalici[ith] - vyhryKoalici[jth]));
                            }
                        }
                    }

            }
        }


 S+="here";
        String T2="";
        T2+="banzhaf";

        Integer swingove=0;

for(int p=0;p<pocetHracu;p++) {
    swingove+=isSwing[p];

}
String strPokus="";
if(canBanzhaf==1) {
    strPokus = "banzhaf ";
} else {
    strPokus="banzhaf err ";




}

float[] banzh=new float[pocetHracu];
for(int p=0;p<pocetHracu;p++)
{
    banzh[p]=(float) isSwing[p]/(float) swingove;

}


         String strPokus2="shap ";

        for(int i=0;i<pocetHracu;i++) {
         //   S+=(" "+String.valueOf(shap[i]));
            strPokus2+=String.format("%.2f ",shap[i]);
            strPokus+=String.format("%.2f ",banzh[i]);
        }


   // tv6.setText(strPokus2+"\n"+strPokus+"\nswing"+isSwing[0]+"swingPrvni:"+isSwing[1]+"\nH"+swingove);

        tv6.setText("11111111111\n"+strPokus2+"\nA\n"+strPokus+"\nB");
        tv6.setSingleLine(true);
        tv6.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        tv6.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        tv6.setSelected(true);

//        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_test);
     /*   tv6.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        tv6.setSingleLine(true);
        tv6.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        tv6.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        tv6.setFocusable(true);

*/

    /*    TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        txt.setText("This is the infinite marquee");
        txt.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        txt.setSingleLine(true);
        txt.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        txt.setSelected(true);
      */

    }

    public void click4(View view) {
        //

        if (g) {

            linear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);
            if (N == 1) {
                linear.setText("1");
            }

            String a = linear.getText().toString();
            N = Integer.parseInt(a);
            N++;
            linear.setText(N.toString());


        }
    }
    public void click7(View view) {
        if (g) {

            //
            linear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);
            if (N == 0 || N == 1) {
                linear.setText("1");
            }

            String a = linear.getText().toString();
            N = Integer.parseInt(a);
            if (N > 1) N--;
            linear.setText(N.toString());


        }
    }

    public  String stf(String a,Integer l) {
        if(l==0) { return a; }
        l--;
        return stf("0"+a,l);

    }
    public void click2(View view) {
        if (g) {
            g = false;

            String col1;
            String col2;
            //  String playerChanged;

            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);


            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            TextView c = new TextView(this);

            //EditText etUserInfoNewValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);
            //  a = editText.getText().toString();

            tv.setId(202);


            tv.setText("This is text");
//
            tl.addView(row);

            row.addView(tv);

            int sf = Integer.toBinaryString(N - 1).length();
            for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
                //String.format("%010d",(
                String jl = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
                String jl2 = stf(jl, sf - jl.length());
//koal[x]=jl2;
                col1 = "(" + x + ")" + jl2;
                // col1 = "(" + x + ")"+Integer.toBinaryString(x);
                col2 = "1";

                //col3 = "(" + x + ") Column 3";
                //col4 = "(" + x + ") Column 4";

                TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);

                TextView column1 = new TextView(this);
                TextView column2 = new TextView(this);
                EditText editText1 = new EditText(this);

                editText1.setId(330 + x);
                // String stringAnswer = editText1.getText().toString();

                TextView column3 = new TextView(this);
                // TextView column4 = new TextView(this);
                editText1.setText("0        ");
                column1.setText(col1);
                column1.setText(col1);
                column2.setText(col2);
                //column3.setText(col3);
                //column4.setText(col4);

                // column1.setText(stringAnswer);

                newRow.addView(column1);
                newRow.addView(editText1);


                newRow.addView(column3);
                // newRow.addView(column4);

                tl.addView(newRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams());
            }


        }
    }

    }
```

XML XML XML XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_span="@integer/material_motion_duration_long_2"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
    android:foregroundGravity="fill_horizontal|center_horizontal"
    android:foregroundTint="@color/purple_200"
    android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="10"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_columnWeight="12"
        android:accessibilityLiveRegion="none"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#1DE9B6"
            android:onClick="click2"
            android:text="Generate"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/simpleEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:digits="10"
            android:hint="Number of coalitions appear here"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textColor="#FF0000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="12"
            android:layout_columnWeight="12"
            android:accessibilityLiveRegion="none"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="25mm"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:foregroundTint="#FF0000"
                android:foregroundTintMode="src_over"
                android:onClick="click4"
                android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="4"
                android:text="Increase"
                android:textSize="11dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="25mm"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:foregroundTint="#FF0000"
                android:foregroundTintMode="src_over"
                android:onClick="click7"
                android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="4"
                android:text="Decrease"
                android:textSize="11dp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#00E5FF"
            android:backgroundTintMode="add"
            android:onClick="click5"
            android:text="Power indices" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="Shapley and Banzhaf" />



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMarque"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="AHA"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: Could you include where and how `tv6` was declared and instantiated? 
Also, could you include the XML of that element particular element that `tv6` is making reference to?

Comment: @acarlstein I've included the entire code: MainActivity and activity_main.xml. Could you detect the bug why the text is not moving but is stationary ??

Comment: Ok. Please don't take this personally. I'm trying to provide you with some positive feedback so you can solve your issue or at least have more changes to solve it. The reason I say this is that the code is a little convoluted which makes it harder to analyze. Below, I will add more comments, each comment with an advice that can help you out.

Comment: 1) Try to obtain the following book: Clean Code by Robert C. Martin. 
It is a very good book and I highly recommend it. Read it. It will help you in the future.

Comment: 2) Separate your logic from the UI activity.  Your logic can work on a separate thread which would prevent the UI activity to halt. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

Comment: 3) Break your code into small methods. Either your method does one thing or your method call multiple methods for which each of those method does one thing and one thing only. This will help you to debug and spot where the issues could be easily. Also, you can group those methods into separate classes, organizing your code for reusability and better maintenance.

Comment: 4) Don't use single character variables unless is to indicate an index of a small loop. Give your variables a meaning. You shouldn't have to remember what each single character variable should be holding in, inside your head. Also, it makes it harder for someone else to help you.

Comment: 5) When I compare this line `editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(330+i);` with the XML, it doesn't makes sense. If you are going to have multiple edit texts, perhaps you could create them dynamically in the constructor, store the reference to them into an Arraylist, append them into the element that will hold them, finally you can iterate and manipulate them in the code.

Comment: 6) Move this line `TextView tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);`, above this line `tv6.setText("11111111111\n"+strPokus2+"\nA\n"+strPokus+"\nB");`. Always, try to keep the declaration and instantiation of a variable, as close as you can to the code that will be using it.

Comment: @acarlstein Your advice is extensive but it hasn't helped me to find the bug.   I'm really a beginner to Android and I'll try make use of your comments. Could you give me here a MWE of MARQUEE that would really work ? I'll then try to incorporate it into my code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have nothing at hand that you can copy-and-paste. In the industry, the current format of the code is called "spaghetti code" which makes it way harder to debug for others. Therefore, I'm advising doing a refactoring the code into a format where other people can help you. Also, if you can break it down into small methods, you can write unit tests to test such methods, increasing the changes to pin point where the issue is.

Comment: @acarlstein Please see my edit.I've done what you suggest.  I've separated MARQUEE from the rest of the code (into activity_main.xml) but it (the text `AHA`) is still not moving :-(

Comment: @acarlstein I have now working MARQUEE ! Still I would like to know how can I set when a new cycle begins in MARQUEE: it is currently a bit delayed about 1/3. How do I enlarge it or delay it to 100% ?

Comment: I'm glad you make your marquee to work. About your question, I'm not sure.
Perhaps you should create a new question, with the new version of your code?

Comment: @acarlstein Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71982882/how-can-i-make-a-letter-t-in-marquee-blinking)  mine latest request