# How can I make a letter (T) in MARQUEE blinking?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, invisible

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71930146/rotating-text-marquee-is-not-appropriate?noredirect=1#comment127171721_71930146) one.

I have made my MARQUEE rotating quite well. Please see my code below. Now I would like to make the letter "T" blinking but `<blink>T</blink>` doesn't seem to work. Can someone give me a MWE for this matter which would make "T" below blinking?

I have an idea how to do it, but I'm somehow unable to realize it:

I could make the "T" part of a new TextView and let it set invisibility and visibility turn on and off.

```
TextView tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMarque2);
        tv7.setSingleLine(true);
        tv7.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        tv7.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        tv7.setSelected(true);
 
        tv7.setText(Html.fromHtml("**<p style=color:green>  *&nbsp;T*</p>\n<ul><li>*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;* *&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p style=color:green;>*</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p style=color:red;>*</p>*  *&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;           </li></ul>"));
```

XML

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMarque2"
            android:layout_width="24mm"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textColor="#00E5FF"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="AHA2"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: fromHtml only supports a very limited number of tags.  Blink is not one of them.  You can probably do it by creating a custom Spannable and animating it yourself.  But it will be hard to get that to work embedded within other HTML, your best bet is to drop HTML and make the spannables entirely yourself.

Comment: Android does not support CSS in `TextView` plus `fromHtml` has a limited HTML markup support. Try to implement a `WebView` instead.

Comment: @acarlstein I would definitely need a more exact hint in the form of a MWE...!

Comment: You can do `val html = "<html><body><p>Hello world</p></body></html>"; 
val baseUrl = "https://whatever-url-here.com/"; webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, html, "text/html", null, baseUrl)` as shown in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/load-local-content)

Comment: @acarlstein the field `mWebView` flashes red. Also, I do not know what to usbstitute for `baseUrl` what's its semantics/purpose ??

Comment: based on the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/load-local-content) I provided you, I think the baseUrl isn't important in this case... I think. You are going to have to go over the documentation to figure that out.